# Problems with OpenGL tilemap rendering using glDrawArraysInstanced

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

Im working on my 2D tile map sidescroller game in c++, Im using few libraries like openGL, openAL etc.

Right now im reworking my render part of my game to make it better from performance side, before i started working on it, I had working version, but it was calling something like 180isch draw calls every frame, which is bad.

So i decided to go with instanced rendering for each texture in my game (if I use 90 textures on my map, i will try to render 90 draw calls, but if texture is not on my screen i will skip it), when i got to it and tried to render something i got cornered, I did some calculations and everything should be fine but it isnt.

```
if (game->data->currentWorld != 0)
{
    tileSizeX = (2.0f / tileXsideCount);
    tileSizeY = (2.0f / tileYsideCount);
    float worldXoffset = getWorldOffsetX();
    float worldYoffset = getWorldOffsetY();
    float playerXoffset = getPlayerOffsetX();
    float playerYoffset = getPlayerOffsetY();
    int tileXoffset = getTileOffsetX();
    int tileYoffset = getTileOffsetY();

    int* textRenderCount = new int[game->data->currentWorld->textureCount];

    float vertices[] =
    {
        -1 + tileSizeX, -1 + tileSizeY , 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f, // top right
        -1 + tileSizeX, -1, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, // bottom right
        -1, -1, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, // bottom left
        -1, -1 + tileSizeY, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f  // top left
    };

    unsigned int indices[] = {
                    0, 1, 3, // first triangle
                    1, 2, 3  // second triangle
    };

    for (int i = 1; i < game->data->currentWorld->textureCount; i++)
    {
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
        glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
        glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        int offsetIndex = 0;

        unsigned int texture;

        if (game->data->loadedTextures[i] != NULL)
        {
            texture = game->data->loadedTextures[i];
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Renderer::RenderLoop - texture not found for id: " << i << endl;
        }

        // position attribute
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        // color attribute
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        // texture coord attribute
        glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(6 * sizeof(float)));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

        tempShader->use();
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

        for(int x = 0; x < game->data->currentWorld->sizeX; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < game->data->currentWorld->sizeY; y++)
            {
                if (
                    x > (tileXoffset - (tileXsideCount / 2) - 1) &&
                    x < (tileXoffset + (tileXsideCount)+1) &&
                    y >(tileYoffset - (tileYsideCount / 2) - 1) &&
                    y < (tileYoffset + (tileYsideCount)+1)
                    )
                {
                    if (game->data->currentWorld->world[x][y]->id == i)
                    {
                        if (game->data->debugTiles)
                        {
                            std::cout << "For tile: x: " << x << " y: " << y;
                        }
                        float offsetX = { ((x*1.0f) - worldXoffset)*tileSizeX};
                        float offsetY = { ((y*1.0f) - worldYoffset)*tileSizeY};
                        if (game->data->debugTiles)
                        {
                            std::cout << " offset is: " << offsetX << offsetY << endl;
                            std::cout << "worldXoffset is : " << worldXoffset << endl;
                            std::cout << "worldYoffset is : " << worldYoffset << endl;
                        }
                        stringstream ss;
                        std::string indexText;
                        ss << offsetIndex;
                        indexText = ss.str();
                        tempShader->setVec2(("offset[" + indexText + "]").c_str(), offsetX, offsetY);
                        offsetIndex++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (game->data->debugTiles)
        {
            std::cout << "RenderCount for last render request:" << offsetIndex+1 <<endl;
            game->data->debugTiles = false;
        }
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glDrawArraysInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES,0, 6,offsetIndex+1);
    UnloadSceneBuffers();
    }
```

and here my functions to return offsets:

```
float Renderer::getWorldOffsetX()
{
    if (game->data->currentChar->xPos < tileXsideCount / 2)
    {
        return 0.0f;
    }
    else if(game->data->currentChar->xPos > game->data->currentWorld->sizeX - (tileXsideCount/2))
    {
        return (game->data->currentWorld->sizeX - (tileXsideCount / 2));
    }
    else
    {
        return (game->data->currentChar->xPos - tileXsideCount/2);
    }
};


float Renderer::getWorldOffsetY()
{
    if (game->data->currentChar->yPos < tileYsideCount / 2)
    {
        return 0.0f;
    }
    else if (game->data->currentChar->yPos > game->data->currentWorld->sizeY - (tileYsideCount / 2))
    {
        return (game->data->currentWorld->sizeY - (tileYsideCount / 2));
    }
    else
    {
        return (game->data->currentChar->yPos - tileYsideCount/2);
    }
};

float Renderer::getPlayerOffsetX()
{
    if (game->data->currentChar->xPos < tileXsideCount / 2)
    {
        return -1.0f + (game->data->currentChar->xPos*tileSizeX);
    }
    else if (game->data->currentChar->xPos > game->data->currentWorld->sizeX - (tileXsideCount / 2))
    {
        return +1.0f - (tileSizeX*((game->data->currentWorld->sizeX-tileXsideCount) - game->data->currentChar->xPos));
    }
    else
    {
        return 0.0f;
    }
};

float Renderer::getPlayerOffsetY()
{
    if (game->data->currentChar->yPos < tileYsideCount / 2)
    {
        return -1.0f + (game->data->currentChar->yPos*tileSizeY);
    }
    else if (game->data->currentChar->yPos > game->data->currentWorld->sizeY - (tileYsideCount / 2))
    {
        return +1.0f - (tileSizeY*((game->data->currentWorld->sizeY - tileYsideCount) - game->data->currentChar->yPos));
    }
    else
    {
        return 0.0f;
    }
};

int Renderer::getTileOffsetX()
{
    if (game->data->currentChar->xPos < tileXsideCount / 2)
    {
        return 0 + tileXsideCount/2;
    }
    else if (game->data->currentChar->xPos > game->data->currentWorld->sizeX - (tileXsideCount / 2))
    {
        return (game->data->currentWorld->sizeX-(tileXsideCount/2));
    }
    else
    {
        return game->data->currentChar->xPos;
    }
}

int Renderer::getTileOffsetY()
{
    if (game->data->currentChar->yPos < tileYsideCount / 2)
    {
        return 0 + tileYsideCount / 2;
}
    else if (game->data->currentChar->yPos > game->data->currentWorld->sizeY -(tileYsideCount / 2))
    {
        return (game->data->currentWorld->sizeY - (tileYsideCount / 2));
    }
    else
    {
        return game->data->currentChar->yPos;
    }
}
```

and here are my shaders:

Vertex:

```
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0) in vec2 aPos;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 aColor;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 aTexCoord;

out vec2 TexCoord;

uniform vec2 offset[198];

void main()
{
    vec2 currentOffset = offset[gl_InstanceID];
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos + currentOffset,0.0f,1.0f);
    TexCoord = aTexCoord;
}
```

Fragment:

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec3 ourColor;
in vec2 TexCoord;

uniform sampler2D ourTexture;

void main()
{
    FragColor = texture(ourTexture, TexCoord);
}
```

and this is my shader set vec2 function (its mostly the same as on learnopengl.com):

```
void setVec2(const std::string &name, float input1,float input2)
{
    glUniform2f(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), input1,input2);
}
```

Edit:
This is what i see:

[image]

Comment: Your vertex data doesn't line up with your vertex specification, I count 7 floats per vertex in the actual data and you're using 8 in the specification.

Comment: @immibis thank you, that fixed it